# How to find if all elements of a list are present in a list of dictionaries?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I'm trying to develop a little script in Python but I've never used this language.

I have a structure that is something like this:

```
dict = [
    { "id" : 1,
      "people" : [ { "name" : "Sarah",
                     "surename" : "something"
                   },
                   { "name" : "Luke",
                    "surename" : "something"
                   },
                   { "name" : "Chris",
                   "surename" : "something"
                   }
                 ]
    },
    { "id" : 2,
      "people" : [ { "name" : "Jhon",
                     "surename" : "something"
                   },
                   { "name" : "Luke",
                    "surename" : "something"
                   },
                   { "name" : "Ronald",
                   "surename" : "something"
                   }
                 ]
    }
]
```

and I have another list of values, such as `name_list = ["Sarah", "Luke"]`.

I need to find all the IDs of the structure such that all the names in the `name_list` are present inside the list of dictionaries `people`.

I've tried something like this but this does not work.

```
for person in dict:
   if all(name_list in p["name"] for p in person["people"]):
      # Do something with person["id"]
```

It is important to me to find all the IDs of the list of dictionaries that contains **all** the names the name_list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ids = [item['id'] for item in d if all(name in [person['name'] for person in item['people']] for name in name_list)]
print(ids)
>>> [1]
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `dict` is a built-in function and shadowing it could break something for you later (e.g. `isinstance(obj, dict)` won't work).

Assuming your input is stored in `data` variable:

```py
result = [
    d["id"] 
    for d in data 
    if not set(name_list) - {p['name'] for p in d['people']}
]
```

Here `{p['name'] for p in d['people']}` is a `set comprehension`. The result would be a unique set of names for `people` struct, e.g `{Sarah, Luke, Ronald}`.

Then we use the set difference to find which names are *not* in the `name_list`: `set(name_list) - {Sarah, Luke, Ronald} == set()`.

The difference will be equal to an empty set if all names from the name_list are in the `people` struct.

So our goal is to find structs in which this difference will be an empty set.

`set` arithmetic will be much faster than using `in` operator with list.

```
In [1]: %timeit [item['id'] for item in d if all(name in [person['name'] for person in item['people']] for name in name_list)]
1.43 µs ± 17.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

In [2]: %timeit [d["id"] for d in data if not set(name_list) - {p['name'] for p in d['people']}]
869 ns ± 2.64 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```